# SQL / Limit (another query)

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have 2 tables. One of them holds the limit  numbers.

And i am trying to run an sql like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='1' LIMIT (another query)
```

Comment: What is the question? What did you try? How did it fail? How can we help?

Comment: Please tag if it is MS SQL and / or MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The Select TOP clause limit the number of rows. You can put an expression in it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can't do that using regular querys. 
LIMIT clause does not allow variables.  LIMIT clause only accepts constant numbers.

You have to use Stored Procedures instead regular querys.

Try use something like this inside an SP code:

```
DECLARE offset bigint
SELECT your_field INTO offset FROM your_table where your_conditions
SELECT * FROM other_table LIMIT offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

\You do what I have suggested to several people is generate SQL from a select statement and then execute that.  Here is my solution:

```
SELECT "select * from other_table LIMIT ", your_field 
FROM your_table where your_conditions
```

Then execute this new SQL.  Of course this works best in UNIX/Linux and with a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='1' LIMIT ?";
SET @limit = (another query);
EXECUTE stmt USING @limit;
```