# Get LIMIT value from subquery result

Tags: mariadb, subquery, with-statement

I would like to use the LIMIT option in my query, but the number of expected rows is stored in another table. This is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
select * from table1 limit (select limitvalue from table2 where id = 1)
```

When I only run the subquery, the result is 6, as expected.

I prefer working with a WITH statement if possible, but that didn't work eiter.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a prepared statement to get the limit of queries from the other table because the limit clause does not allow non constant variables as parameter:

```
PREPARE firstQuery FROM "SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT ?";
SET @limit = (select limitvalue from table2 where id = 1);
EXECUTE firstQuery USING @limit;
```

[The source of the sql query from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10889522/18184495)

Comment: I had to add LIMIT ? but now it works. Thanks!

Comment: the temporary variable @limit represent the subquery to execute with your first query (it replaces the question mark)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of MariaDB's [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) function in a CTE to count the rows to be output, comparing that against the `limitvalue`. For example:

```sql
WITH rownums AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
  FROM table1
)
SELECT *
FROM rownums
WHERE rn <= (SELECT limitvalue FROM table2 WHERE id = 1)
```

**Note** Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is **not** guaranteed to give you the same results every time. You should include an `ORDER BY` clause in the `OVER` part of the `ROW_NUMBER` window function. With the sample data in my demo, you might use something like:

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mark DESC)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ee0a28f03f5708289b36628d8e3b0f60)

Comment: Thank you Nick. This works even better, because with this solution, I can use the query as a view. In the solution with the prepared statement I did not manage to do that. Thanks a lot!